# How to combine chained menu and custom-select

Tags: javascript, chained-select, custom-selectors

I have added a form at the bottom of [my webpage](https://www.parisaspersiankitchen.com/contact.php) using the custom-select:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

But in the sidebar I use the chained select menu:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chainedmenu/index.htm

In the chained menu I would also like to see the custom-select dropdown styling, but for some reason it does not show. Is there a conflict in the scripts, or am I missing something here?

This is the js of the custom-select form field:

```
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /* For each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item: */
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box: */
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

And this is the chained select code:

```
var _disable_empty_list = false;
var _hide_empty_list = false;
var onclickaction = "alert"

function goListGroup() {
  for (i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arguments[i].selectedIndex != -1) {
      var selectedOptionvalue = arguments[i].options[arguments[i].selectedIndex] value
      if (selectedOptionvalue != "") {
        if (onclickaction == "alert")
          alert(selectedOptionvalue)
        else if (newwindow == 1)
          window.open(selectedOptionvalue)
        else
          window.location = selectedOptionvalue
        break
      }
    }
  }
}

if (typeof(disable_empty_list) == "undefined") {
  disable_empty_list = _disable_empty_list;
}
if (typeof(hide_empty_list) == "undefined") {
  hide_empty_list = _hide_empty_list;
}

var cs_goodContent = true,
  cs_M = "M",
  cs_L = "L",
  cs_curTop = null,
  cs_curSub = null;

function cs_findOBJ(obj, n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].name == n) {
      return obj[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function cs_findContent(n) {
  return cs_findOBJ(cs_content, n);
}

function cs_findM(m, n) {
  if (m.name == n) {
    return m;
  }

  var sm = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < m.items.length; i++) {
    if (m.items[i].type == cs_M) {
      sm = cs_findM(m.items[i], n);
      if (sm != null) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return sm;
}

function cs_findMenu(n) {
  return (cs_curSub != null && cs_curSub.name == n) ? cs_curSub : cs_findM(cs_curTop, n);
}

function cs_contentOBJ(n, obj) {
  this.name = n;
  this.menu = obj;
  this.lists = new Array();
  this.cookie = "";
};
cs_content = new Array();

function cs_topmenuOBJ(tm) {
  this.name = tm;
  this.items = new Array();
  this.df = 0;
  this.addM = cs_addM;
  this.addL = cs_addL;
}

function cs_submenuOBJ(dis, link, sub) {
  this.name = sub;
  this.type = cs_M;
  this.dis = dis;
  this.link = link;
  this.df = 0;

  var x = cs_findMenu(sub);
  this.items = x == null ? new Array() : x.items;

  this.addM = cs_addM;
  this.addL = cs_addL;
}

function cs_linkOBJ(dis, link) {
  this.type = cs_L;
  this.dis = dis;
  this.link = link;
}

function cs_addM(dis, link, sub) {
  this.items[this.items.length] = new cs_submenuOBJ(dis, link, sub);
}

function cs_addL(dis, link) {
  this.items[this.items.length] = new cs_linkOBJ(dis, link);
}

function cs_showMsg(msg) {
  window.status = msg;
}

function cs_badContent(n) {
  cs_goodContent = false;
  cs_showMsg("[" + n + "] Not Found.");
}

function cs_optionOBJ(text, value) {
  this.text = text;
  this.value = value;
}

function cs_emptyList(list) {
  for (var i = list.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list.options[i] = null;
  }
}

function cs_refreshList(list, opt, df) {
  cs_emptyList(list);

  for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {
    list.options[i] = new Option(opt[i].text, opt[i].value);
  }

  if (opt.length > 0) {
    list.selectedIndex = df;
  }
}

function cs_getOptions(menu) {
  var opt = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.items.length; i++) {
    opt[i] = new cs_optionOBJ(menu.items[i].dis, menu.items[i].link);
  }
  return opt;
}

function cs_updateListGroup(content, idx, sidx, mode) {
  var i = 0,
    curItem = null,
    menu = content.menu;

  while (i < idx) {
    menu = menu.items[content.lists[i++].selectedIndex];
  }

  if (menu.items[sidx].type == cs_M && idx < content.lists.length - 1) {
    var df = cs_getIdx(mode, content.cookie, idx + 1, menu.items[sidx].df);

    cs_refreshList(content.lists[idx + 1], cs_getOptions(menu.items[sidx]), df);
    if (content.cookie) {
      cs_setCookie(content.cookie + "_" + (idx + 1), df);
    }

    if (idx + 1 < content.lists.length) {
      if (disable_empty_list) {
        content.lists[idx + 1].disabled = false;
      }
      if (hide_empty_list) {
        content.lists[idx + 1].style.display = "";
      }

      cs_updateListGroup(content, idx + 1, df, mode);
    }
  } else {
    for (var s = idx + 1; s < content.lists.length; s++) {
      cs_emptyList(content.lists[s]);

      if (disable_empty_list) {
        content.lists[s].disabled = true;
      }
      if (hide_empty_list) {
        content.lists[s].style.display = "none";
      }

      if (content.cookie) {
        cs_setCookie(content.cookie + "_" + s, "");
      }
    }
  }
}

function cs_initListGroup(content, mode) {
  var df = cs_getIdx(mode, content.cookie, 0, content.menu.df);

  cs_refreshList(content.lists[0], cs_getOptions(content.menu), df);
  if (content.cookie) {
    cs_setCookie(content.cookie + "_" + 0, df);
  }

  cs_updateListGroup(content, 0, df, mode);
}

function cs_updateList() {
  var content = this.content;
  for (var i = 0; i < content.lists.length; i++) {
    if (content.lists[i] == this) {
      if (content.cookie) {
        cs_setCookie(content.cookie + "_" + i, this.selectedIndex);
      }

      if (i < content.lists.length - 1) {
        cs_updateListGroup(content, i, this.selectedIndex, "");
      }
    }
  }
}

function cs_getIdx(mode, name, idx, df) {
  if (mode) {
    var cs_idx = cs_getCookie(name + "_" + idx);
    if (cs_idx != "") {
      df = parseInt(cs_idx);
    }
  }
  return df;
}

function _setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value;
}

function cs_setCookie(name, value) {
  setTimeout("_setCookie('" + name + "','" + value + "')", 0);
}

function cs_getCookie(name) {
  var cookieRE = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
  if (document.cookie.search(cookieRE) != -1) {
    return RegExp.$1;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

// ----
function addListGroup(n, tm) {
  if (cs_goodContent) {
    cs_curTop = new cs_topmenuOBJ(tm);
    cs_curSub = null;

    var c = cs_findContent(n);
    if (c == null) {
      cs_content[cs_content.length] = new cs_contentOBJ(n, cs_curTop);
    } else {
      delete(c.menu);
      c.menu = cs_curTop;
    }
  }
}

function addList(n, dis, link, sub, df) {
  if (cs_goodContent) {
    cs_curSub = cs_findMenu(n);

    if (cs_curSub != null) {
      cs_curSub.addM(dis, link || "", sub);
      if (typeof(df) != "undefined") {
        cs_curSub.df = cs_curSub.items.length - 1;
      }
    } else {
      cs_badContent(n);
    }
  }
}

function addOption(n, dis, link, df) {
  if (cs_goodContent) {
    cs_curSub = cs_findMenu(n);

    if (cs_curSub != null) {
      cs_curSub.addL(dis, link || "");
      if (typeof(df) != "undefined") {
        cs_curSub.df = cs_curSub.items.length - 1;
      }
    } else {
      cs_badContent(n);
    }
  }
}

function initListGroup(n) {
  var _content = cs_findContent(n),
    count = 0;
  if (_content != null) {
    content = new cs_contentOBJ("cs_" + n, _content.menu);
    cs_content[cs_content.length] = content;

    for (var i = 1; i < initListGroup.arguments.length; i++) {
      if (typeof(arguments[i]) == "object" && arguments[i].tagName && arguments[i].tagName == "SELECT") {
        content.lists[count] = arguments[i];

        arguments[i].onchange = cs_updateList;
        arguments[i].content = content;
        arguments[i].idx = count++;
      } else if (typeof(arguments[i]) == "string" && /^[a-zA-    Z_]\w*$/.test(arguments[i])) {
        content.cookie = arguments[i];
      }
    }

    if (content.lists.length > 0) {
      cs_initListGroup(content, content.cookie);
    }
  }
}

function resetListGroup(n) {
  var content = cs_findContent("cs_" + n);
  if (content != null && content.lists.length > 0) {
    cs_initListGroup(content, "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit to place a working copy of the code that reproduces this issue IN your question. FWIW I will NOT be clicking links to pretty much anywhere here. blame the miscreants of the world.

Comment: Added the javascripts of which I believe there is a conflict.

Comment: Hi there. The scripts that I mentioned here are what I use on the  webpage that I linked to. My guess is that there is a conflict in these two scripts.

Comment: That is a pretty large code wall to ask someone to debug for you.  You mention "style" but don't include a "functioning" minimal set of code with any CSS.  I would suggest you paste your code here and perhaps heed some of those warnings: https://jshint.com/

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss What is this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75110700/revisions
The css code can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: Thing is, I don't understand anything of javascript, but I would like to see both scripts combined.

Comment: I simply formatted the code wall you posted.  The code you posted IMHO could use a lot of cleanup BUT to "combine" those is a copy/paste and then evaluate all the details in there - which are non-trivial in this case.  Time to put your learning cap on; perhaps starting with the site I noted to evaluate warnings and things like that to address.